# How to update variable even after page refresh in PHP within the same document

Tags: php

What is the best way to have a variable that increases on page refresh.

I am connected to an API that only allows page pagination.  I am showing a max of `$pageSize = 100;` items per page so when this gets to less then `100` I would like the variable to return to its default state of `1`

Comment: You can't do it with `$_GET`. Use a session variable to persist data between refreshes.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks I have edited my question :) Am I able to get an example?  I am over thinking things

Comment: Title says "keep variable constant" while first line "increases on page refresh". A bit confusing imo.

Comment: It's better to reveal the end goal instead just asking about a problem that you think will help you achieving it. In comments below you revealed that it has something to do with cron job which is a sign of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a variable that increases on page refresh you can do:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION["counter"])){
         $_SESSION["counter"] = 1;
    }
    else {
         $_SESSION["counter"]++;
    }

?>
```

Note that the variable is stored in session so it will be a different counter for every user.

Comment: It will only be one user a cron job would this make a diff? and would I just do an else if $total less then 100 set counter to 1?

Comment: I was in doubt if you intended a global counter or a local counter in a normal page. If it is only accessed by a cron job it should do what you are looking for. The else if you want to add also works without any issues